# Backbone can create objects, but not fetch them

Tags: django, backbone.js, tastypie

I'm trying out Backbone.js for the first time. I'm not new to Django and so I'm trying to build a Backbone-powered frontend to a Django app. After some research, I decided that Tastypie is probably the easiest to go.

After much wrangling, I have this problem: I can create objects just fine, but I can't fetch any of them.

So I can do this:

```
var foo = new LabSite()
var newInfo={name:"Mine",site_code:"FRED"}
foo.save(newInfo)
```

And I can see a new LabSite in the admin named "Mine" with an ID of 1.

When I try this:

```
var bar = new LabSite({id:1})

bar.fetch({
    success: function (bar) {
        alert(bar.toJSON());
    }
})
```

I don't see the alert.

On the object that is turn back it has this as the response:

```
responseText: "callback({"id": "1", "name": "Mine", "resource_uri": "/api/v1/labsite/1/","site_code": "FRED"})"
```

So it was returned, the value isn't there. Maybe something doesn't understand the response?

I tried using this backbone-tastypie project, but it didn't change anything:
https://github.com/amccloud/backbone-tastypie

My ModelResource is quite simple:

```
class LabSiteResource(ModelResource):

    def determine_format(self, request):
       return  'text/javascript'

    class Meta:
       queryset = LabSite.objects.all()
       authorization= Authorization()
```

And if I go to `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/labsite/1/` I see:

```
   callback({"id": "1", "name": "Mine", "resource_uri": "/api/v1/labsite/1/", "site_code": "FRED"})
```

Any idea why I can't fetch anything?

*EDIT* Based on a comment below, I tried to catch the error.

```
  var errorInfo = {};
  var bar = new LabSite({id:1})
  bar.fetch({
      success: function (bar) {
        alert(bar.toJSON());
      },
  error: function(a1,a2,a3) {
      errorInfo=[a1,a2,a3]

   }
   });
```

`errorInfo` didn't provide a lot of helpful information -- this is what it was:

```
    > errorInfo[0]
    d
    _escapedAttributes: Object
    _pending: Object
    _previousAttributes: Object
    _silent: Object
    attributes: Object
    changed: Object
    cid: "c1"
    id: 1
    __proto__: x
    > errorInfo[1]
    [...]
    readyState: 4
    responseText: "callback({"id": "1", "name": "Mine", "resource_uri": "/api/v1/labsite/1/", "site_code": "FRED"})"
    setRequestHeader: function (a,b){if(!v){var c=a.toLowerCase();a=u[c]=u[c]||a,t[a]=b}return this}
    state: function (){return c}
    status: 200
    statusCode: function (a){if(a){var b;if(v<2)for(b in a)r[b]=[r[b],a[b]];else b=a[x.status],x.always(b)}return this}
    statusText: "OK"
    [....]
    > errorInfo[2]
    Object
    error: function (d,e){e=d===b?e:d;a?a(b,e,c):b.trigger("error",b,e,c)}
    success: function (d,e,f){if(!b.set(b.parse(d,f),a))return!1;c&&c(b,d)}
    __proto__: Object
```

The `errorInfo[1].status` seems to indicate the the communication was perfectly find and `errorInfo[1].responseText` is the correct data. I may be more confused now than before.

Comment: Can you try putting an error callback in the fetch and see if its going in that callback? If yes, inspect the arguments. It might help.

Comment: I put in my error handling the the results above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fetch response JSON wrapped into `callback` function. Is it jsonp? Backbone expects pure JSON.

Comment: That is the ticket. I changed the  `determine_format` method to return 'application/json' and that worked.  I knew it was something silly.